# PHP RegEx pattern for repeating within the string

Tags: php, regex, self, repeat

I am trying to make regex for this string :

```
This is some string <select> this is another string <select var1> another string which can contain special characters <select var2> another variable string <select var1,var2>
```

I need to select all the strings not in select tag.

```
Select all string not within <select> tag
```

Can anyone help ? using PHP preg_match

Comment: you should know how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What have you tried? What errors you're getting?

Comment: @Mohammad: Yes, I posted this question after 3 hours of searching.

Comment: @Carlos : I tried (.*)/<select/>(.*) , it works fine on single instance of select tag but on multiple instance it is not returning anything. Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by using [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$str = 'This is some string <select> this is another string <select var1> another string which can contain special characters <select var2> another variable string <select var1,var2>';

$arr = preg_split('/\<.*?\>/',$str);
print_r($arr);
```